# Custom serialization

Tags: c++

I have a container class B and it has certain number of items of A. I want to serialize it for sending either over wire or save it to disk.

```
class A {
public:
    bool b;
    long c;
};

struct B {
public:
    int na;
    bool bb;
    A** a;
};
void send(unsigned char* ptr, int sizeb) {
    int i = sizeof(B);
    B* b = new B();
    b->a = (A**)malloc((int)*ptr * sizeof(A*));
    while (i < sizeb) {
        memcpy(b->a[i], ptr + i, sizeof(A));
        i += sizeof(A);
    }
}
```

The first member of B is the number of contained A items. In this case it's three.

```
int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    b->na = 3;
    b->bb = true;
    b->a = (A**)malloc(b->na *sizeof(A*));
    for (int i = 0; i < b->na; i++) {
        b->a[i] = new A();
        b->a[i]->b = true;
        b->a[i]->c = (i+1) * 100;
    }
    int sizeb = sizeof(B) + b->na * sizeof(A);
    unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeb);
    memcpy(ptr, (unsigned char*)&b, sizeof(B));
    for (int i = 0; i < b->na; i++)
        memcpy(ptr+i*sizeof(A), (unsigned char*)&b->a[i], sizeof(A));
    send(ptr, sizeb);
    return 0;
}
```

First I allocate enough contigous space for storing B and the three A's. In the send method I don't get back the *na* value. What's wrong?

Comment: I stole the C tag. C has no `new` operator and doesn't require casting the `void` pointers returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Use [boost::serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: @user4581301 ironically we call them c-style casts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not copying what you think you're copying:

```
memcpy(ptr, (unsigned char*)&b, sizeof(B));
for (int i = 0; i < b->na; i++)
    memcpy(ptr+i*sizeof(A), (unsigned char*)&b->a[i], sizeof(A));
```

`b` is already a pointer to `B`, so when you take its address you now have a `B **`.  The same happens with `&b->a[i]` which evaluated to a `A **`.  You also overwrite the instance of `B` with the first instance of `A`.

You already have pointers to the data you want to copy, so pass those directly to `memcpy`, and add `sizeof(b)` to `ptr` when adding the instances of `A`.

```
memcpy(ptr, b, sizeof(B));
for (int i = 0; i < b->na; i++)
    memcpy(ptr+sizeof(B)+i*sizeof(A), b->a[i], sizeof(A));
```

Then in your `send` function, you're not deserializing the instance of `B`.  You need to do that as well.

```
B* b = new B();
memcpy(b, ptr, sizeof(b);
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the code is serializing the a mostly-uninitialized `B` that was created within the `send` function, not the `b` created and initialized in `main`

Comment: that was my previous attempt, in turn at the send()  I don't get the 3 by the (int)*ptr

Comment: @user4581301 this is a demo without any sense. I just want to highlight the problem

Comment: thanks @dbush, +sizeof(B) helped. In turn memcpy(b, ptr, sizeof(b)) can't be good, because b contains pointers to the 3 A's therefore b->a must be allocated first, isn't?

Comment: @Franziee  It's not a problem.  You perform the `memcpy` first, which copies each of the members including the old pointer valid, then you overwrite the old pointer value with a newly allocated buffer to hold an array of `A *`.